# AS3 loading multiple image

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm loading images using XML. Right now, the situation is that the image is only loaded onto the last entry in the XML. cv is a popup that contains a holder called cHolder and a text field called ct. The images will be loaded onto cHolder. How do is solve this so that image will loaded onto all cHolder?

```
for each (var projectName:XML in projectAttributes) 
    {
        //trace(projectName);
        var projectDP:XMLList = projectInput.project.(@name == projectName).displayP;
        trace(projectDP);

        var cv:MovieClip = new cView();
        catNo += 1;
        if(catNo % 5 == 0)
        {
            catY += 137;
            catX = -170;
            cv.x = catX;
            cv.y = catY;
        }
        else
        {
            cv.x = catX;
            cv.y = catY;
            catX += 112;
        }

        imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(projectDP));        
        cv.cHolder.addChild(imageLoader);
        cv.ct.text = projectName;
        cv.buttonMode = true;
        this.addChild(cv);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use a separate loader object for each image. Something like this:

```
for each (var projectName:XML in projectAttributes) {
    ...
    imageLoader = new Loader();
    imageLoader.load(new URLRequest(projectDP));
    ...
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend LoaderMax (http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/) Its fantastic for loading multiple items.

A sample would be:

```
var queue:LoaderMax = new LoaderMax({onComplete:onComplete});

queue.append(new ImageLoader("img/photo1.jpg", {name:"photo1"}));
queue.append(new ImageLoader("img/photo2.jpg", {name:"photo2"}));
queue.append(new ImageLoader("img/photo3.jpg", {name:"photo3"}));
queue.append(new ImageLoader("img/photo4.jpg", {name:"photo4"}));

queue.load();

function onComplete() {
  trace("All done");
  cv.cHolder.addChild(queue.getContent("myPhoto1")); // etc
}
```

You could use array's etc to store the references etc.